# Is there any solution for this?

Tags: math, probability, discrete-mathematics

It's not a homework question or assignment, it just one interesting thought that comes out of my mind.

Assume there is a player with a 25% critical strike chance at the beginning. If the player hit the enemy and critical strike does not come out, the player's critical strike chance increase 25%, else(means critical strike success) reset critical strike chance to 25%.

After 3 times no critical strike, the 4th time is a 100% critical strike. Any time player hit a critical strike, critical strike chance reset to 25%.

Is there any accurate or approximate answer to this case, what is the overall critical strike chance of the player? Is there any formula that we can use to calculate the overall probability in this case?

I was thinking to implement a program to simulate this case to see the probability, but I wish if there is any formula can solve it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

There are four states the player can be in:

1. 25% chance of getting a critical hit
2. 50% chance of getting a critical hit
3. 75% chance of getting a critical hit
4. 100% chance of getting a critical hit

If we knew how frequently the player was in each state, we could multiply the probability of being in the state with the probability of getting a critical hit in that state, add up all the products, and get the chance of getting a critical hit in general.

How frequently is the player in each state:

1. let's call this the relative frequency with which the player is in this state F1. The player moves to this state whenever (1) he was in state 1 and got a critical, (2) he was in state 2 and got a critical, (3) he was in state 3 and got a critical, or (4) he was in state 4 (in which case he definitely got a critical). Therefore, we have that `F1 = 0.25 * F1 + 0.50 * F2 + 0.75 * F3 + F4`
2. let's call this one F2. We get `F2 = 0.75 * F1`.
3. let's call this one F3. We get `F3 = 0.50 * F2`.
4. let's call this one F4. We get `F4 = 0.25 * F3`.

Putting everything together:

```
F1 = 1.00 * F1
F2 = 0.75 * F1
F3 = 0.50 * F2 = 0.375 * F1
F4 = 0.25 * F3 = 0.09375 * F1
```

We can verify the equation we recovered involving `F1` holds true with these values. We must now normalize these coefficients so they sum to 1:

```
var   freq       norm freq
F1    1.00000    ~ 0.450
F2    0.75000    ~ 0.338
F3    0.37500    ~ 0.169
F4    0.09375    ~ 0.043
      -------
      2.21875
```

Now, we multiply the pairs and sum up:

```
0.25 * 0.450 = 0.11250
0.50 * 0.338 = 0.16900
0.75 * 0.169 = 0.12675
1.00 * 0.043 = 0.04300
               -------
               0.45125
```

In summary, I'd put the number of critical hits at around 45.125%.